# How can I do a full text search with a phrase of more than one word, using Sequel full_text_search?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I am using ruby, Sequel and postgres. I have implemented full text search as follows:

```
get '/full_text_search' do
search_term = params[:search_term] 

result = DB[:candidates].full_text_search(:experience, search_term).map do |row|
 { :id => row[:id], :first => row[:first], :last => row[:last], :designation => row[:designation], :company => row[:company], :email => row[:email], :phone => row[:phone], :city => row[:city], :country => row[:country], :industry => row[:industry], :status => row[:status], :remarks => row[:remarks], :experience => row[:experience] }
    end
  halt 200, result.to_json
end
```

This is executed by passing a search term from a text box, via an ajax call, so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#full_text_search").click(function(){ 
var search_term = $("#search_box").val();
    $.getJSON("/full_text_search?search_term="+search_term, function(data) {
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {  
        //do something with returned data here
         });//end each
          });//end getJSON
     });//end click
});//end doc
```

If my search term is just one word, "private" for example, I get the results back no problem but if I try a search term of 2 words (or more) "private equity", for example, I get an error and no data is returned.

So my question is how can I execute full text search (as above) with a phrase of 2 or more words?

I have already tried encapsulating the passed parameter with '' and "" unsuccessfully.

All help gratefully received. Thank you.

Comment: Please show the actual SQL executed by the application, from the PostgreSQL logs with `log_statement = 'all'` or the Rails logs with SQL logging enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's full text searching does not handle phrase searching natively.  The best you can do is look for entries containing both words, using `&`: `full_text_search(:experience, 'term1 & term2')`, followed by using `LIKE '%term1 term2%'` if you want to do actual phrase searching.

I'll look into adding an `:phrase=>true` option to `full_text_search` that will make it operate as a phrase search.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, and Craig. I feared this was the case.